# JavaScript package to create a search bar like Kibana

Tags: javascript, user-interface, search, frontend, kibana

Does anyone know a JavaScript package that allows to create a multi-keyword filter query like for example the searchbar of Kibana. StackOverflow, Trello and Gitlab have similar capabilities, but not all have support for multiple filters at once or don't have autocomplete for all possible search filters.

I am looking for something similar to [select2 with tags](https://select2.org/tagging#tagging-with-multi-value-select-boxes), but then the predefined options are all the available filters and after selecting a filter you can enter the desired value. For instance, you enter "user:" after which you can select one of your users. This will then result in "user:John" in your search bar (and underneath it keeps track of the user id for the actual search). Next you can add another filter etc. resulting in powerfull search queries while using just one search box.

Also see this Kibana search example:
[image: Kibana Search Example]

I am just wondering what already exists, before I start making this.

Comment: I think the behavior you need has to be done by your self - how should a javascript package know about your users, tags and so on. I think you could build your in memory database about your wished tags, usersnames and call it by listeners of typing text into your search bar.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It could work via JSON structure provided on load, or via an ajax call to a specific end point on entering characters, similar to what select2 supports. However, in a select2 I am missing the part that you can select a filter and then search for a value and then submit the filter:value string as a tag.

Comment: Hi @Hans , I am currently in search of exactly the same. It has been a while, were you able to find some existing package matching your needs?